# Compute a linear combination of tensors in Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensor

I am attempting to compute a linear combination of `n` tensors of the same dimension in Tensorflow. The scalar coefficients are Tensorflow `Variable`s.

Since `tf.scalar_mul` does not generalise to multiplying a vector of tensors by a vector of scalars, I have thus far used `tf.gather` and performed each multiplication individually in a python for loop, and then converted the list of results to a tensor and summed them across the zeroth axis. Like so:

```
coefficients = tf.Variable(tf.constant(initial_value, shape=[n]))
components = []
for i in range(n):
    components.append(tf.scalar_mul(tf.gather(coefficients, i), tensors[i]))
combination = tf.reduce_sum(tf.convert_to_tensor(components), axis=0)
```

This works fine, but does not scale well at all. My application requires computing `n` linear combinations, meaning I have `n^2` gather and multiply operations. With large values of `n` the computation time is poor and the memory usage of the program is unreasonably large.

Is there a more natural way of computing a linear combination like this in Tensorflow that would be faster and less resource intensive?

Comment: You could try to avoid appending. If you need to use the list at all, appending is usually slower than allocating the memory beforehand if you know the size already.
A test run with 1M operations gave this result:
Append: 0.21716690063476562 seconds,
Without Append: 0.1666109561920166 seconds
This can sum up to some time in large scales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use broadcasting. Assuming `coefficients` has shape `(n,)` and `tensors` shape `(n,...)` you can simply use

```
coefficients[:, tf.newaxis, ...] * tensors
```

here, you would need to repeat `tf.newaxis` as many times as `tensors` has dimenions besides the one of size `n`. So e.g. if `tensors` has shape `(n, a, b)` you would use `coefficients[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis]`

This will turn coefficients into a tensor with the same number of dimensions as `tensors`, but all dimensions except the first one are of size `1`, so they can be broadcast to the shape of `tensors`.

Some alternatives:

- Define `coefficients` as a variable with the correct number of dimensions in the first place (a little ugly in my opinion).
- Use `tf.reshape` to reshape `coefficients` to `(n, 1, ...)` instead if you don't like the indexing syntax.
- Use `tf.transpose` to shift the dimension of size `n` to the *end* of `tensors`. Then the dimensions align for broadcasting without needing to add dimensions to `coefficients`.

Also see [the numpy docs on broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -- it works essentially the same way in Tensorflow.

Comment: I'm having a slight issue with these approaches:
`tf.reshape(coefficients, tensors.shape)` won't work as the shape of tensors is partially unknown, it is essentially a vector of different network's weights. e.g. it could be of shape [n, ?, 10]

Comment: What about the other options? As long as the _number_ of dimensions of `tensors` is known this should work. Also, you cannot reshape `coefficients`to `tensors.shape` since they generally don't have the same number of elements.

Comment: Alright - I see what you're saying, it needs to be of shape `[n, *([1] * tensor_dimensions)]` if that makes sense. This method is a considerable improvement on my previous effort, memory usage is an order of magnitude lower, I'll accept the answer! :)

Comment: Exactly! I slightly reworded the `reshape` part to make it clearer. The idea of all options is to align the shapes of `coefficients` and `tensors` such that the former can be properly repeated along the dimensions of the latter for efficient element-wise multiplication (simulating the scalar multiplication you want).

Answer (score 0):

There is a new PyPI module called TWIT, Tensor Weighted Interpolative Transfer, that will do this fast.  It is written in C for the core operations.